# Criar uma função ou usar o código diretamente?

Tags: javascript

O que é mais recomendado?

Em uma situação que eu posso usar dos dois modos (eu posso escolher, vai funcionar do mesmo jeito).

O que é recomendável fazer? Criar uma função ou inserir o script diretamente no arquivo JS?

Exemplo básico:

```
if(2*5 == 10){
   console.log('Verdade!');
}
```

Ou

```
function conta() {
   if(2*5 == 10){
      console.log('Verdade!');
   }
}
conta();
```

Isso foi só um exemplo, mas resume o que eu quero saber.

Mais uma vez, reforço que eu sei que em certos lugares eu não vou poder criar o código diretamente porque não vai fazer sentido e vão ocorrer erros, mas tem algumas coisas tão pequenas que no dia-a-dia a gente precisa fazer, que gostaria de saber qual jeito é recomendado, se existe algo na velocidade de processamento, etc...

Se essa pergunta for baseada em opiniões, me desculpem!

Comment: Acho que é meio de opinião pessoal, mas eu diria que se fores usar em mais do que 1 sitio o mesmo código: cria uma função para ficar mais DRY

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo dessas "coisas tão pequenas que no dia a dia a gente precisa fazer" para se perceber melhor que tipo de coisas são ?

Comment: Cada caso tem suas peculiaridades e, como não é um exemplo real, é difícil lhe responder.

Comment: Isac, eu trabalho por exemplo numa empresa que é um E-Commerce, e outra empresa fornece um Magento SaaS pra gente, ou seja, eu não tenho acesso ao Backend e em algumas páginas também do mesmo, e as vezes preciso mudar por exemplo, texto de alguns botões (Exemplo isso). Eu simplesmente pego o jQuery $('.minhaClass').text('Novo nome') ou era melhor eu criar uma função? Mesmo sabendo que eu não preciso reutilizar aquele código de novo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resposta é "depende". Saber qual é a melhor alternativa depende muito do que você quer fazer. Em alguns casos uma função é melhor, em outros, ter apenas o código é melhor.

No entanto, quando o código começar a ficar grande e complicado, é sinal de que deveria ser melhor modularizado, e é aí que entram as funções e até mesmo objetos. Logo, exceto para os casos mais bobinhos e simplórios, ter tudo dentro de funções e objetos produz um código em que é mais fácil dar manutenção. Por outro lado os casos bobinhos e simplórios podem ser bastante comuns.

Comment: Realmente não tem uma forma correta ao meu ver e sim depende muito do caso, para código que pode ser ser reutilizado é sempre bom criar uma função única!

Answer (score 1):

Eu prefiro criar `function` mesmo que se possa usar sem elas pois imagino em sites com varias `Scripts` onde uma `var` pode interferir na outra assim usando `function` evitaria conflito pois ela so existe dentro daquela `function` n interferindo em códigos de fora

exemplo com function:

```
var i =1;
    function ex(){
     var i=0;

    }
    ex();


if(i==1){
         console.log('Verdade!');
        }else{
console.log('amarelo!');
}
```

nesse exemplo acima ele ira entrar em verde.

exemplo sem function:
insira o código aqui

```
    var i = 1;
    var i=0;
if(i==1){
             console.log('Verdade!');
            }else{
    console.log('amarelo!');
    }
```

ele iria entrar no amarelo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Cada caso pode ser um caso específico, mas é necessário que você observe esses itens para as boas praticas da necessidades de se criar , ou não, uma função.

Você ira criar uma função para:

- Para permitir o reaproveitamento de código já construído(por você ou por outros programadores). No seu exemplo uma função de soma seria útil como função para poder ser reaproveitada sempre que tivesse necessidade de calcular as somas.
- Para evitar que um trecho de código que seja repetido várias vezes dentro de um mesmo programa; Imagine ter que a rotina mode por algum motivo, vc teria que sobrescrever todos os lugares que o trecho de código apareça. Se vc modulariza, você consegue alterar em apenas um local e estará tudo resolvido.
- Para que os blocos do programa não fiquem grandes demais e, por conseqüência, mais difíceis de entender;
- Para separar o programa em partes(blocos) que possam ser logicamente compreendidos de forma isolada.

Tendo essas regras em mente você vai perceber quando será necessário criar uma função ou não.

**Sempre pense no seu código de forma escalonável. As vezes você não precisa de uma rotina em um método ou função no momento, mas pela estrutura do projeto é possível prever que será necessário em modificações e melhorias futuras**

Answer (score 1):

É opcional você deixar o código diretamente ou em uma função, mas eu aconselho sempre que puder utilizar uma função, vou te dar um exemplo.

Pense na situação em que você tem uma função que recebe notas de alunos de escola e que te retorna quais foram aprovado e dentro dela você verificas varias competências para aprovação do aluno. Se você utilizar funções, quando você precisar de alterar a forma que será verificado a aprovação do aluno você vai alterar apenas na função e se você utilizar o código direto, você vai ter alterar uma parte da estrutura do sistema. Quando estamos aprendendo com aplicações pequenas e simples isso não faz diferença, mas agora imagina isso em uma grande aplicação.